# Filter datagridview copy without binding source

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, filter, datagridview, filtering

I get a copy of datagidview#1 with this code:

```
Private Sub copytable()
    Dim sourceGrid As DataGridView = Me.DataGridView1
    Dim targetGrid As DataGridView = Me.DataGridView2
    Dim targetRows = New List(Of DataGridViewRow)

    For Each sourceRow As DataGridViewRow In sourceGrid.Rows

        If (Not sourceRow.IsNewRow) Then

            Dim targetRow = CType(sourceRow.Clone(), DataGridViewRow)

            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In sourceRow.Cells
                targetRow.Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).Value = cell.Value
            Next

            targetRows.Add(targetRow)
        End If

    Next

    'Clear target columns and then clone all source columns.

    targetGrid.Columns.Clear()

    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In sourceGrid.Columns
        targetGrid.Columns.Add(CType(column.Clone(), DataGridViewColumn))
    Next

    'It's recommended to use the AddRange method (if available)
    'when adding multiple items to a collection.

    targetGrid.Rows.AddRange(targetRows.ToArray())

End Sub
```

This code copy all headers,columns and rows into a second `DataGridView`, then I want to filter this second `DataGridView` but I can't (BindingSource.Filter) the binding source does not exist.
How can I create `Bindingsource` for the second `DataGridView`??

Comment: You need more than just a `BindingSource` in order to filter the data. When you set the `Filter` property of a `BindingSource`, it simply passes that on to its own data source **IF** that data source supports it. The only way that is going to happen is if the data source is a `DataTable` or you implemented `IBindingListView` in your own type. Basically, the solution to your problem is to populate a `DataTable` with the copied data, bind that to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid. If the first grid's ultimate data source is a `DataTable`, just copy that.

Comment: You dont need to copy any data at all.  A DataView can show some rows from a DT in one DV and a DV with the inverse filter can show them in the other.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]